# Angular parent child scope with service

Tags: angularjs, scope, parent

I'm stuggling with some concepts of Angular, in particular the flow of variable and scope.

What I'm trying to do is to set a variable in a child controller and pass it to a parent scope. Consider this simple example:

```
module.controller('childController', childController);
function childController($scope,$http,$window, hexafy) {
    $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(17);      
}

module.controller('parentController', parentController);
function parentController($scope, hexafy) {

}

module.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
```

Then my mark-up is as follows:

```
{{hex}}

<section data-ng-controller="listingsViewController">....</section>
```

The calculation is handled by the child controller but as you can see I want to pass the variable to the 'parent'. I have read about 'parent' scope but I understand that this is not best practise so I'm attempting to use a service. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve this and I would actually recommend following approach (using common `$scope object variable` in both parent and child controller) instead of using service as it is much easier and cleaner approach.

You can then access the `hex` value in parent controller using `$scope.shareValue.hex`.

```
module.controller('childController', childController);
function childController($scope,$http,$window, hexafy) {
    $scope.shareValue.hex = hexafy.myFunc(17);
}

module.controller('parentController', parentController);
function parentController($scope, hexafy) {
    var shareValue = {
       hex: ''
    };
    $scope.shareValue = shareValue;
}
```

======================================================================
Updated with using service: 
Please refer to Matthew Cawley post on comment below.

Comment: I read the $parentScope is not recommended as it can causes problem at a later date. I am gonig to try as you have suggested above but I'm also curious to see how the service works. I can't find any examples though and keep going around in circles

Comment: @whyyie You can get the value from the service without doing a click or using `$emit`, in your code, if you put your function in an expression `{{ clickHere() }}` in the view, it will execute whenever it changes.

Comment: @MatthewCawley I am a bit blur. Could you reproduce it in plunker on how it could be done? I changes the value in the child input textbox, how the value could be reflected on parent directly without the use of `click` or `$emit`.

Comment: Plunker - [How to retrieve the value from the service directly, whenever it changes](https://plnkr.co/edit/m0mgtyn8gCV384nd0wfZ?p=preview)

Comment: @MatthewCawley Bravo. Thank you today i have learn new things from you.

Comment: I'd still do it your way, which is why I haven't posted an answer. For sharing one value, creating an object on a parent controller is no big deal (you have to be pragmatic). And in reply to @AlanA's concern about using `$parent` scope, it should be noted that that isn't what's being suggested. `$parent` refers to the *immediate* parent and so will break as soon as an extra `ng-repeat` is added (which creates a new scope layer), whereas with controller `$scope` inheritance, the shared object will always be available as long as the `childController` is within the `parentController` (any level).

Comment: @matthew-cawley so am I right to be cautious of $parent scope as it's quite simple to kill the scope at a later date, is that correct. Appreciate your answers guys thanks

Comment: Yes correct, avoid `$parent` where possible because it can break *very* easily and is widely considered a bad practice. Accessing a scope object using scope inheritance though as in this example, it's simple, and is far less likely to break (than `$parent`). The only slight negative is not knowing by looking in the view where the object is declared, and you have to avoid foolishly overwriting the object in the child controller (just don't do it!). Using a service/factory is generally considered the better practice for sharing data, is it necessary here though? **In summary, it just depends**.

Comment: [A better example of using services](http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/) just to throw that into the mix. I've not seen it done like this before, so I've learnt something new today too! (everyone's a winner!)

Comment: @matthew-cawley my actual use case is passing a message to an alert that resides in my page template that all pages on my webapp use. So various controllers may possible need to pass a message to the parent controller. This probably does justify a service I guess, my initial simplified example likely doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You should first set value using a service function in your child controller and then in your parent controller use a getvalue function in your parent controller.

Your setvalue and getvalue function should be in service.

Controller code

```
app.controller('childController', childController);
function childController($scope,$http,$window, hexafy) {
    $scope.childValue = "Value in child controller"
    hexafy.setValue($scope.childValue);      
}

app.controller('parentController', parentController);
function parentController($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.parentValue = hexafy.getValue()
}
```

Service code

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {

  var value = "";
  this.setValue = function(val) {
    value = val
  },

  this.getValue = function() {
    return value;
  }


    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
```

Html code

```
<div ng-controller="childController">
      <h2>Child controller</h2>
      {{childValue}}

    </div>

     <div ng-controller="parentController">
       <h2>Parent controller</h2>
      {{parentValue}}

    </div>
```

have a look at working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6NULbvk1L47OweDJIGYf?p=preview)

Comment: awesome thanks I was stuggling with the get/set method